# How to pick specific columns Pandas dataframe when checking against NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in Python that looks something like

```
       AccountID_x    AccountId  AmountCD_x  AmountDOC_x  AmountDoc_x  
1              NaN  4001001copa       52.53        52.53          NaN   
2              NaN  4001001copa       52.53        52.53          NaN   
3      4001001copa          NaN       52.53        52.53          NaN   
4              NaN  4001001copa       52.53        52.53          NaN
```

This dataframe is the result of a merge command to merge 2 dataframes together.  What I want to do now is create a new column that will add either AccountID_x or AccountId based on which on is not Nan, so in the above example rows 1, 2, 4 would have the value of AccountId in it and row 3 would have the value from AccountID_x in some new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also propagate `fillna` using `apply`:

```
df2['newcolumn'] = df2[['AccountID_x','AccountId']].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill')[-1], axis=1)
```

Or equivalently (in your case):

```
df2['newcolumn'] = df2[['AccountID_x','AccountId']].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='bfill')[0], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use combine_first to combine the two

```
df['new_col'] = df['AccountId'].combine_first(df['AccountID_x'])

df['new_col']

1    4001001copa
2    4001001copa
3    4001001copa
4    4001001copa
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['AccountId'] if pd.isnull(x['AccountID_x']) else x['AccountID_x'], axis=1)
```